# Raspberry Pi cannot soft reboot

Tags: raspbian

I have seen many questions regarding rebooting issues when shuting down the Pi.

I have a Pi with Raspbmc installed and just happen to have the opposite problem: any reboot command (whether through XBMC menu "Reboot" or SSH "sudo reboot") will cause my Pi to shuts down without rebooting - I then have to hard reboot through power unplug/replug. Not so great for SSH remote management.

Incidentally, I use a powered-USB hub to both connect more peripherals and power my Pi.

Has anyone had the same problem? Any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: Reboot on Rasbpian shuts down the Pi? Try unplugging everything from USB and then try reboot.

Comment: Might be a power-saving-"feature" of the hub you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bypassed the USB hub as hinted by Gerben... indeed did the trick - pi now reboots normally.

If anyone knows a USB hub with appropriate behavior for the Pi, I will be much interested :)